# Concatenating strings in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

How to concatenate strings in C, not like `1` + `1` = `2` but like `1` + `1` = `11`.

Comment: I'm afraid your question doesn't make much sense currently. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Thanks for editing that Vinko, I figured I would just be flamed for my question, but I actually got what I wanted. Thanks stackoverflow.com

Comment: austin, would you mind marking your accepted answer that helps you the most?

Comment: sure, sorry about that. this is my first time using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need string concatenation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char str1[50] = "Hello ";
  char str2[] = "World";

  strcat(str1, str2);

  printf("str1: %s\n", str1);

  return 0;
}
```

from: http://irc.essex.ac.uk/www.iota-six.co.uk/c/g6_strcat_strncat.asp

Comment: Note that strncat() (with the 'n') is extremely hard to use correctly - so don't use it.

Comment: Why is it harder than counting your buffers in strcat?

Comment: @Jonathan:
Don't know about "extremely hard", but it's much safer.

Comment: not *much* safer. There is a reason strlcat() exists. Although that's not a complete fix either. It's just a drop-in improvement.

I'd use snprintf(). It has the best behavior.

Comment: strncat() doesn't guarantee the result is nul terminated. strlcat() does, but may not be widely available. strcat() is blissfully ignorant of the size of the destination buffer. In short, the C standard library is burdened by a lot of history that gets in the way of preventing buffer overruns.

Comment: If I didn't use the [50] above but used just [], the code still works. But is that a memory leak?

Answer (score 7):

To concatenate more than two strings, you can use sprintf, e.g.

```
char buffer[101];
sprintf(buffer, "%s%s%s%s", "this", " is", " my", " story");
```

Comment: ynimous: snprintf is not available everywhere

Comment: many people can only rely on c89. sweet snprintf isn't available for them :(

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at the strcat API.  With sufficient buffer space, you can add one string onto the end of another one.

```
char[50] buffer;
strcpy(buffer, "1");
printf("%s\n", buffer); // prints 1
strcat(buffer, "1");
printf("%s\n", buffer); // prints 11
```

Reference page for strcat

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/

Answer (score 1):

'strcat' is the answer, but thought there should be an example that touches on the buffer-size issue explicitly.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* str1 and str2 are the strings that you want to concatenate... */

/* result buffer needs to be one larger than the combined length */
/* of the two strings */
char *result = malloc((strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1));
strcpy(result, str1);
strcat(result, str2);
```

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1, always. http://drj11.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/sizeofchar-is-1/

Comment: This leaks memory by overwriting the pointer `result`, and needs at least one strcpy() as well. Also, it extends str1, but the implication is that you intended both str1 and str2 to be read only.

Comment: malloc() may return NULL, causing UB.

Answer (score 0):

strcat(s1, s2). Watch your buffer sizes.