# Concatenating String in C

Tags: c, string

I have a method that concatenates two c string. The method returns a new one. It works fine. Is there a way to make this method void, and just modify the first one?

EDIT: I cannot use strcopy or any other function from the string.h library. It is also suppose to be up to the caller to make sure s1 has enough space to accommodate s2.

```
char *str_glue(char *s1, char *s2) 
{
char *r; //return string
int len1, len2;
int i, j;

len1 = str_length(s1);
len2 = str_length(s2);

if ((r=(char*)malloc(len1 + len2 + 1))==NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}

for (i=0, j=0; i<len1; i++, j++) {
    r[j] = s1[i];
}
for (i=0; i<len2; i++, j++)
{
    r[j] = s2[i];
}

r[j] = '\0';

return r;

}


int main() {

char* x = "lightning";
char* y = "bug";
char *z = str_glue(x, y);
printf("%s\n", z);
}
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968316/concatenating-strings-in-c

Comment: The standard function `strcat()` does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. `*s1` is a char[] that already has a fixed length. If you write past that length you'll stomp on memory that is not inside of `*s1`. You have to create a new one that is the length of `*s1` + `*s2` to avoid this problem like you have done already.

**Edit:** I guess you could write a function that does what you want if `*s1` is big enough to hold itself and `*s2`. But otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard function `strcat()`:

> The **strcat()** and **strncat()** functions append a copy of the null-terminated string **s2** to the end of the null-terminated string **s1**,
>   then add a terminating `\0'.  The string **s1** must have sufficient space to hold the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `realloc` of `s1` provided you allocate the same on the heap. By modifying your code as this, I am able to achieve the same functionality as expected by you.

```
void str_glue(char **s1, char *s2) 
{
    int len1, len2;
    int i;
    char *curstr = *s1;

    len1 = strlen(curstr);
    len2 = strlen(s2);

    curstr=(char*)realloc(curstr, (len1 + len2 + 1));

    for (i=0; i<len2; i++)
    {
        curstr[(len1+i)] = s2[i];
    }
    curstr[(len1+len2)] = '\0';
}
```

and `main` function as

```
int main()
{
    char* x;
    char* y = "bug";
    x = (char *)malloc(32);
   strcpy(x, "lightning");

   str_glue(&x, y);
    printf("%s\n", x);
}
```

You would require to include `stdlib.h` for `realloc` definition.

**P.S:** I am assuming that you don't plan to use the standard `C` library functions like `strcat` or others.